# Figuring out R error-handler stack

Tags: r, error-handling

Having spent more time chasing my tail on this than is healthy, I'm just going to have to ask:

In R, how can one figure out what error handlers are in force at a given point in the code?  Somebody somewhere is gracefully intercepting my errors, and I want them to stop!

Comment: I think you're going to have to provide a specific example. I'm particularly confused by "Somebody somewhere is gracefully intercepting my errors". What you do you mean by _your_ errors? Are you calling `stop` or `warning` and expecting certain output but not getting it? Or are you having trouble using `try` or `tryCatch`?

Comment: "Somebody" is intercepting your errors? You should go back on your medications.

Comment: It's slightly complicated.  Through a home-modified version of the "evaluate" package I'm running code to set up a Shiny session, running server/UI code provided on the fly by a user.  I'd like to report to the user when that code generates errors.  But somewhere between evaluate and the user's code a handler is catching all error throws and turning them into harmless messages on stderr.  I've tried hooking or disabling all the try/tryCatch invocations I can see, to no avail.  So I'm asking whether there's a way to discover which handler will intervene when the user's code generates an error.

Comment: Probably a question for the R devel mailing list. This seems to be handled by internal R functions.

Comment: I found the culprit by picking through a `traceback(1)` and examining anything that looked like an error handler.  It turned out that errors were being suppressed deep within the http-message handling of the `httpuv` package.  Rather than hack around that package, I realised I could add a check in the calling code based on geterrmessage(): even when a `stop` is suppressed, the error is still recorded.  That allows me to detect an error and re-throw it for handling in my own code.